# What is the meaning for the aosp repo tool's manifest file having remote element with attribute fetch =".."

Tags: android-source, repo

Ok so in the manifest file of android repo tool. After executing
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

We have a .repo folder which contains a manifest folder inside which we have the default.xml which contains the info on which repos to pull.

According to https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md
for a remote the fetch should have the url which should be prefixed before every project.

But the default.xml's fetch fied contains

```
<remote  name="aosp"
           fetch=".."
           review="https://android-review.googlesource.com/" />
```

shouldn't the fetch field be android.googlesource.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

".." means the upper directory of the manifest. The manifest is host on https://android.googlesource.com with the directory "platform", the upper direcotory is ".". So ".." means "https://android.googlesource.com" here.